# Does the following sentence make any sense grammatically?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

"I agree with your point of him shouldn't have having been there in the first place"?

I get confused and mixed up when using the past tense and should/would/have sometimes.

Thanks.

Comment: "your point about how he shouldn't have been there" or "your point that he shouldn't have been there" are more natural than "point of".

Answer (score 0):

I think it difficult to use modal verbs (could, should, might ...) in this way. If you wish to keep the “having to ...” construction, you could express the thought differently by not using the modal *should*. Let’s start with the simple positive statement:

“I agree with your point of his having to be there in the first place”.

The negative version is then:

“I agree with your point of his not having to be there in the first place”.